# javascript console.log() improvement

Tags: javascript, logging, console, npm

Here is the example

```
var x = "foo";
console.log(x);
=> x: foo
```

is it possible to override console.log() / warp the console.log() / npm package / _   etc... can help ?

Comment: What do you mean, what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: The specific output you're asking for can't be done.  What is passed to `console.log()` in your case above is a reference to a string value, not a reference to `x`.  So, there is no knowledge of the fact that it came from the `x` variable in the function.  Thus, you can't output the fact that it was `x`.  You would have to pass the name of the variable as a separate argument.

Comment: What should happen when you do `console.log(someFunction())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do what you've shown in the question, no, for the simple reason that the *value* of `x` is passed to the function. There is no connection from the argument that the function receives back to the `x` variable or the context in which the `x` variable exists, and so there's no way for `console.log` (or any replacement of it you would author) to determine that the name was, in fact, `x`.

Since `console.log` accepts multiple arguments, you can do:

```
console.log('x', x);
```

...which is a simple and easy way to get output similar to what you want.

You can also log a temporary object:

```
console.log({x:x});
```

In ES2015 (aka ES6) that can even just be:

```
console.log({x});
```